# How to dynamically create spring beans based on properties file and then autowired them to use in another bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create beans after reading some properties from the application.yaml file and then want to inject them to other beans. How this can be achieved?

Comment: can you show the code with input and output senario

Comment: this might be of some help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590942/creating-spring-beans-dynamically-runtime-using-method

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `@Value` annotation to inject properties from application.yaml as fields into your class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create your bean on your own, e.g.:

```
@Bean
public YourBeanClass createBean() {
  return new YourBeanClass()
}
```

You can then inject properties from your application.yaml with the `@Value` annotation in the bean creation method:

```
@Bean
public YourBeanClass createBean(@Value("${path.to.key}") String propertyValue) {
  return new YourBeanClass(propertyValue)
}
```

When you create a bean like that, you can simply autowire it, e.g. in a service:

```
@Service
public class ServiceName {
  public ServiceName(YourBeanClass autowiredType) {

  }
}
```

And the bean `YourBeanClass` will be autowired into the constructor of your `ServiceName` service class for usage. The dependency resolution will be done by spring automatically.

Comment: Much appreciated but I want to create multiple beans of same class based on the number of configurations defined in yaml file. How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Darkwyng/stars/blob/master/parent/addons/src/main/java/com/pim/stars/mineral/imp/MineralTypeCreator.java)'s an example, that creates a bean for each value in a property list. This creates a different number of implementations depending on property values:

```
@Configuration
public class MineralTypeCreator {

    @Bean
    public List<MineralType> mineralTypes(final MineralProperties mineralProperties) {
        return mineralProperties.getTypeIds().stream().map(GenericMineralType::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private class GenericMineralType implements MineralType {

        public GenericMineralType(final String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    // ...
```

Having the properties passed into the `@Bean`-method is still nice, even if you only need to create a single bean.