# how to dynamically autowire a bean in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've come across a few examples on Stack Overflow related to this issue, such as [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137278/how-to-dynamically-create-spring-beans-based-on-properties-file-and-then-autowir) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105044/inject-spring-bean-dynamically) and an Article [Article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamic-autowire). Despite going through them, I'm still struggling to implement a proper solution. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this?

I have a class named ZendeskClient that requires a token parameter for instantiation. Without this token, the class cannot be instantiated. Here's an example of how the ZendeskClient is typically instantiated:

```
          ZendeskClient zendesk = new ZendeskClient(token)
```

The token is retrieved from the database, and below is a sample implementation of fetching the token: Assume the integrationId comes from spring web controller.

```
public String getToken(long integrationId) {
  var integration = integration.findById(integrationId):
  var integrationToken = integrationTokenRepository.findById(integration.getId)
  return integrationToken.getToken();
}
```

With this information, I'm trying to achieve the following in a ZendeskService class:

```
public class ZendeskServiceImpl {

@Autowire
public ZendeskClient client;

}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You have all the components, just make the `ZendeskClient` construction in an `@Bean` method. Call retrieve token, use that to create the client. As it is in an `@Bean` method it will be a spring bean.

Comment: You can either fetch the token from a `Configuration` class and provide it to the `ZendeskClient` and return the instance from a `Bean` method. Alternatively, you can also do this in a `PostConstruct` method in the `ZendeskClient`

Comment: I'm worried about how to pass the integrationId. I'm a bit uncertain. Any example would be highly appreciated.@AbhijitSarkar @M.Deinum

Comment: We don't know where that id comes from so that is impossible for us to answer.

Comment: Assume the id comes from spring web controller. @M.Deinum

Comment: THen just construct the client as you need it.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. Could you please share a sample template? @M.Deinum

Comment: You already provided that yourself. All the code is already there, pass the id along to the service call the method to obtain a token and construct the client as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot autowire object which is not created by spring. So, in your configuration class add bean for ZendeskClient.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {
// some other configuration

   @Bean
   public ZendeskClient getZendeskClient() {
       return new ZendeskClient(getToken(integrationId));
   }
  
}
```

Comment: hi, how to pass the integrationId ?